# Make element consume free space in a container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a page which is supposed to look thus:

[image: The way it's supposed to look]

It's the header here that's the cause of my problems. It contains:

1. An icon, in the far left end, which has a fixed size
2. A title, just to the right of the icon, which takes up just as much space as needed to fit the title text on one line
3. Sometimes, a subtitle arranged below the title
4. Sometimes, a box with some auxiliary stuff arranged to the right of the titles, using up any left-over space

I don't want to nest these elements, for various reasons (including but not limited to perfectionism), and I'm *almost* there... except that I can't get the last box, "auxiliary stuff", to fill the remaining space.

I've built this as columns, with the icon being 100% height, title and subtitle being <50% height, and the aux box being having 100% height. Giving the aux box a fixed width works fine, but when I try to make it grow horizontally with `width: 100%`, the 100% seems to mean "100% of the surrounding box" (in my case, `<heading>`) rather than "100% of the remaining space", which makes it overflow.

```css
html, body { padding: 0; margin: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; font: 10px sans-serif }

/* Colors to please the eyes */
article { border: 5em solid limegreen; }
header { border: 1px solid tomato; }
.icon { background-color: cyan; }
h1 { background-color: magenta; }
h2 { background-color: yellow; }
.aux { background-color: lavender; }

/* Arrange them boxes */
article {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
}
header {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    align-content: flex-start;
    height: 5em;
}
.icon { width: 5em; height: 100% }
h1 { font-size: 200%; margin: 0 }
h2 { font-size: 150%; margin: 0  }
.aux { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
```

```html
<article>
  <header>
    <div class=icon>ICON</div>
    <h1>Main header</h1>
    <h2>Subheading here</h2>
    <div class=aux>MOAR STUFF</div>
  </header>
  <section>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
  </section>
</article>
```

Can I make the last box grow horizontally, *without* changing the markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font: 10px sans-serif
}
/* Colors to please the eyes */

article {
  border: 5em solid limegreen;
}
header {
  border: 1px solid tomato;
}
.icon {
  background-color: cyan;
}
h1 {
  background-color: magenta;
}
h2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.aux {
  background-color: lavender;
}
header {
  height: 5em;
  position: relative;
}
.icon {
  width: 5em;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 200%;
  margin: 0 0 0 calc(5em / 2); /* adjust for the font size */
  float: left;
  height: 1px;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 150%;
  margin: calc(1em * 200 / 150) 0 0 calc(5em / 1.5); /* adjust for the font size */
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
.aux {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <header>
    <div class=icon>ICON</div>
    <h1>Main header</h1>
    <h2>Subheader here</h2>
    <div class=aux>
      MOAR STUFF MOAR STUFF
    </div>
  </header>
  <section>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
  </section>
</article>
```

The advantage is that `.aux` takes on the correct size, so you can for example center stuff in it. The disadvantage is that you lose the background for the main header so you have to fake it on another element. But that can be done.

Comment: Very nice; accepted you are. A few notes from my implementation of it: First, I didn't have to give the `h1` a 1px height, and so I didn't have to give the `h2` a margin-top  _and_ if I had actually cared about the background colors (I used them mostly to show how the boxes flow) that would've worked too.

Comment: Secondly, since the `aux ` box is actually an iframe showing a Google Map, it plays by other rules than normal `div`s (should've mentioned this in my question, probably), I did have to change the markup, which I wanted to avoid, but since this change only involved the map element (and didn't change the relationship between the conceptual elements) I'm okay with it. I wrapped the `iframe` in a `div`, which I gave `display: flex` and then the iframe can `flex: 1` to fill out the available space.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @gustafc Glad it works for you. Have you tried the layout when the subheader is wider than the main header?

Comment: Yes, that was a rather nasty surprise in Chrome with the aux box aligning to the top of the h2. Works fine in Safari and Firefox though, too bad I can't ignore Chrome :-/

Comment: Success, I just managed to fix that by adding even more markup (☹, although it's still just around the iframe so I can live with it). If I wrap the div-and-iframe once more in a div, and the topmost div has display: block, the intermediate display: flex and the iframe has flex: 1 it works in Chrome, too. Phew!

Comment: @gustafc Yeah, that's why I gave a fixed height to h1.

Comment: Aha, I see. Again, clever.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED SOLUTION** (now that CSS Grid is available)

With the advent of CSS Grid, the layout is relatively simple. There is no need to alter the mark-up.

One key rule is this one:

```
grid-template-columns: 5em auto 1fr;
```

It establishes a grid with three columns. The widths of each column are specified, and inline with the requirements of the question.

The `fr` unit is similar in concept to the `flex-grow` property. It is designed to consume free space.

```css
header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 5em auto 1fr; /* set 3 columns at specified widths */
  grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;         /* set 2 rows at specified heights */
  height: 5em;  
}

.icon {
  grid-row: span 2;                    /* span two rows (full height) */
}

h1 {}                                 /* placed automatically based on source order */

h2 {
  grid-column: 2;                      /* placed in column 2 */
}

.aux {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}

/* non-essential decorative styles */
body    { margin: 0; font: 10px sans-serif }
article { border: 5em solid limegreen; }
header  { border: 1px solid tomato;    }
.icon   { background-color: cyan;      }
h1      { background-color: magenta; font-size: 200%; margin: 0; }
h2      { background-color: yellow;; font-size: 150%; margin: 0; }
.aux    { background-color: lavender;  }
```

```html
<article>
  <header>
    <div class=icon>ICON</div>
    <h1>Main header</h1>
    <h2>Subheading here</h2>
    <div class=aux>MOAR STUFF</div>
  </header>
  <section>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
  </section>
</article>
```

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yszvb82d/17/)

---

**OLD (PRE-GRID) SOLUTION**

If you define a width for the column containing the `h1` and `h2`, then getting the auxiliary box ("moar stuff") to stretch the remaining width of its parent is not a problem.

Try this:

HTML (no changes)

CSS

```
h1 {
   font-size: 200%;
   margin: 0;
   width: 10em; /* new */
}

.aux {
   height: 100%;
   width: calc(100% - 10em - 5em - 10em); /* width less header column less icon 
                                             less green border */
}
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t5y28ws8/1/)

Comment: Nice one, but... the headings are supposed to grow with the content (i.e. the title shouldn't wrap, and shouldn't take up more horizontal space than strictly needed). Perhaps I have unreasonable demands, here...

Comment: I've updated my answer with a more efficient (and hopefully, useful) solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any simple way to fix this without changing the markup. The trouble is that you have wrapping and stretching at the same time. If you removed the part that wraps, you could change the flex direction and stretch the final element.

Below is a solution with very little change to the markup. I placed the heading and subheading in a container.

```css
html, body { padding: 0; margin: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; font: 10px sans-serif }

/* Colors to please the eyes */
article { border: 5em solid limegreen; }
header { border: 1px solid tomato; }
.icon { background-color: cyan; }
h1 { background-color: magenta; }
h2 { background-color: yellow; }
.aux { background-color: lavender; }

/* Arrange them boxes */
article {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-content: flex-start;
    height: 5em;
}

.icon, h1, h2 {
  flex-shrink: noshrink;
}

.icon { width: 5em; height: 100% }
h1 { font-size: 200%; margin: 0 }
h2 { font-size: 150%; margin: 0  }

.aux { height: 100%; flex-grow: 1; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Flexicols</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <article>
            <header>
                <div class=icon>ICON</div>
                <div class='subtitled-heading'>
                  <h1>Main header</h1>
                  <h2>Subheading here</h2>
                </div>
                <div class=aux>MOAR STUFF</div>
            </header>
            <section>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
            </section>
        </article>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is precisely the solution I want to avoid. The `h2` is conceptually more related to the `aux` box than to the `h1`, so the grouping markup would be somewhat unsemantic and solely exist for layout and that _really hurts_ my OCD. ;)

Comment: So then why are you structuring it that way? The h2 should be above aux then, not under h1.

Comment: The visual location of the `h2` doesn't matter in terms of semantics. Plus, this question is only about this layout arrangement. Maybe on different screen sizes the `h2` will be above aux. But it doesn't matter either way.

Comment: @gustafc, wile you are talking about semantics, how about esthetics? Those colors burn! For all I know, Akash did give you a proper, and moreover, working solution...

Comment: @RenevanderLende the colors are fine ;) as for this solution, my question was not "how do I achieve this layout", but "how do I achieve this layout _without changing markup_"... I've not yet decided what I consider the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

What essentially needs to be changed (given your rule to leave the HTML as-is), is:

- make `header` fill its parent
- header background to lavender to fake `aux` fill of 100% (`aux` will
  grow as needed)
- min/max height/width of `aux` so it stays inside parent
- give `h1` and `h2` a height of 50% so they wrap.
- `h1` and `h2` need to fill their boxes, so flex grow.

**small update**

- Make header chop off overflow
- Add box-sizing rules to make everything align properly

```css
html,
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit
}
/* Colors to please the eyes */

article {
  border: 5em solid limegreen;
}
header {
  border: 1px solid tomato;
}
.icon {
  background-color: cyan;
}
h1 {
  background-color: magenta;
}
h2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.aux {
  background-color: lavender;
}
/* Arrange them boxes */

article {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}
header {
  background-color: lavender;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  height: 5em;
}
.icon {
  width: 5em;
  height: 100%
}
h1 {
  font-size: 200%;
  margin: 0;
  height: 50%;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 150%;
  margin: 0;
  height: 50%;
}
.aux {
  min-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%
}
```

```html
<article>
  <header>
    <div class=icon>ICON</div>
    <h1>Main header</h1>
    <h2>Subheading here</h2>
    <div class=aux>MOAR STUFF</div>
  </header>
  <section>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
  </section>
</article>
```